# Geting specific response body from response and put in a variable in Postman

Tags: javascript, variables, postman, response

I am trying to set the response in a variable but the response is just an ID, not an object. I used

```
var resposseBody=pm.response.json();
```

or

```
var resposseBody=pm.response.text();
```

but they didn't work. How can I set the response below in a variable?

"3707ff3d-2af9-4ea1-a6aa-08d9a8ee3cb3"

Answer (score 1):

To save that value to a variable, add this to the `Tests` script:

```
pm.globals.set('id', pm.response.text());
```

This is an example using the global scope but the variable can be set at the Environment or Collection level.

There aren't many details in your question so it's difficult to offer any more of a solution than this one.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I ignored something. After your suggestion, I got it.